# Adding a "Create Jira Ticket" view to an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jira, jira-plugin

I work on an Eclipse RCP application and we are trying to encourage people to move from our old trac bug reporting system to our new Jira based system.

Due to users being unfamiliar with Jira, they tend to still report bugs by the old system in preference to the new system. We don't want to force people to  switch by taking down the old trac system, so I thought that if it were **much easier** to report via Jira however, they would be much more likely to switch.

What I was thinking was that I could integrate a "Submit Jira Ticket" view directly into our application, so that submitting a ticket was always a button click away, and where some of the complexity of Jira could be hidden behind default fields added by our application.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Are there already eclipse plug-ins that I could add to my Eclipse RCP configuration, or would I have to write my own view plug-in?

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use the [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) Eclipse plugin which already has a JIRA connector. This lets you create, update, view and search for issues and has been around for a while, so it's very stable.

If you want a simpler form to just submit issues, then you'd probably have to write your own view. JIRA provides a [REST API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) that would support this.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @NickWilson, you can use Mylyn as the vehicle..

Have a look at the extensions points `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core.templates` and `org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs.support`. For an example of their use by Atlassian see the plugin `com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.ui`.

These extension points are used to report bugs via the "Help" >> "Report Bug or Enhancement..." menu item.

Comment: Thanks Tony, knowing what extension points I need to look at should make investigating the Mylyn option much easier. I guess as a first step I should get around to getting Mylyn working in my Eclipse Development environment, something I've been meaning to look at for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Atlassian has a plugin for Eclipse depending on the version of JIRA.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.ide.plugins.eclipse.jira

Once you install this plugin, use that updated eclipse install as base eclipse install and include the feature in your bundled rcp application.